# Console like output in windows with c#.NET

Tags: c#

Is there a control that would allow me a console like output of text? Like cout in c++ or textout in WM PAINT message.

I need to output a two dimensional array and later be able to change background color of each array element. If there are any other ways I could achieve it please do leave a suggestion. However I can't use an array of labels or other controls.

Comment: WPF, Winforms, Webforms, JQuery or console application?

Comment: A RichTextBox with a fixed-pitch font like Courier.

Comment: How about a simple (rich) text box? I don't really understand what you mean with "I can't use labels or other controls" though.

Comment: Although after re-reading I'm wondering whether you are after a grid control? I'm "Lost".

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Write("Text here")
Console.WriteLine("Text here");
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @AalokParikh - wow, is that all you manage to say 1.75 years after my answer? I supposed the -1 vote is yours as well? Ye man, you made friends today :s

Comment: sorry but I didn't vote down for this answer and this is the comment added by review system :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post a screenshot of what you want to do or something ?

Can't you simply use a RichTextBox, or a grid control correctly customized ? There are plenty of solutions, just explain clearly what you want and do yourself a few tries.